# Php - Javascript - How do I know which pages are in color and which are in black and white?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, pdf

This script will split a PDF into single pages and saves them. if I click on an image it changes css class and becomes black and white.

Now the problem for me is to understand **which and how many pages are in color**.

what is the best approach to understand it? 
tk

```html
<?php
$pdf='aaa.pdf';
$image = new Imagick();
$image->pingImage($pdf);
$x = $image->getNumberImages();
echo "
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<script>
function change_autorefreshdiv(id){
    var NAME = document.getElementById(id)
    var currentClass = NAME.className;
    if(currentClass == 'bn'){
        NAME.className = 'colore';
    } else {
        NAME.className = 'bn';
    }
} 
</script>

<style type='text/css'>
.bn{
      -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
      -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
      -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
      -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
      filter: grayscale(100%);
}
body {
      background: #000; 
    }
img {padding:5px;}
</style>

<body>";
for ($i=0; $i <= $x; ++$i){
 $im = new Imagick();
 $im->setResolution(20, 20);
 $im->readImage(''.$pdf.'['.$i.']');
 $im->setImageFormat('jpeg');
 $im->setImageCompression(imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG); 
 $im->setImageCompressionQuality(100);
 $jpegpath = 'jpeg/'.$pdf.'['.$i.'].jpeg';
 $im->writeImage($jpegpath);
 echo "
    <img  width='170px' height='220px' 
    src='$jpegpath' id='$i' class='colore' 
    onclick='change_autorefreshdiv($i)'></img>";
}
echo "
  </body>";
```

[img script in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMehC.png)

Comment: Do you want the _Javascript_ to know which is which, or the _PHP_ to know?

Comment: There's just not enough here for us to help. Are you saying that you want the PHP to understand if the pages of the PDF are in black and white, or if the user clicks an image?  Why does it change from color to b+w in the first place? What's the goal here?

Comment: this is a part of a website I'm building . the user after uploading a PDF must be able to choose which pages to be printed in color, such as black and white. change the class in the css helps the user to get a visual preview . I need to know which pages the user has chosen .. in php ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP runs on the *server*, sends the results (its output) down the line to the *browser*, then ***stops running***, it's done.
The browser receives the output, then renders the HTML and runs the javascript. The PHP code is *out of the game* at this point.

For the PHP (the server, really) to know which is which the browser *will have to tell it*, by sending those facts back to the server.
This could be done by a form submit, or an ajax post; ajax could inform the server once at the end, or continuously as each "page" is selected (clicked) and unselected.

Either form submit or ajax, this will probably be a `POST` to your server such as `http://yourserver.com/yourapplication/process_selections.php` - or could use the same .php file that sent this in the first place.
The important thing to understand is that *this is entirely separate* from the PHP code you posted in your question. *That* code has finished running.  Even if you post back to the same PHP file, that is a *new invocation* so none of the variables you previously had set are still there to be used.

You will have to decide on a strategy to send the information back to the server, and once you have you'll likely have more questions — ask those as specific questions later; the topic is too broad to cover in an answer to *this* question.

---

Tip: in the browser you'll probably want to use javascript to select all the items with the `.bn` and/or the `.colore` class and send information about those back to the server.

Comment: ok , thanks for the reply , therefore the 2 simplest options are: 1) create a form ( with checkboxes ) in which I put the images ( php ) or 2) I count how many times appears the class css bn with the corresponding id (number of page) (javascript )?  for the second option (your tip) have you suggestions? tk

Comment: If you don't have experience with AJAX you may want to stick with a `<form>` — however, you _could_ hide the checkboxes and check them using javascript behind the scenes when the page image is clicked, or you could leave them showing, then check the checkbox and change the image class (`.bn` or `.colore`) when _either_ the checkbox or the image is clicked. Or, using the image as the checkbox label ties clicking on the image to the checkbox. See my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/stephen61/pa9s4ktr/

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!!